# ruby rails assets path for 3rd party

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm attempting to port from Rails 2.3.8 to Rails 3.2.6. My app currently uses 3rd party css/js/images which are placed in `public/<3rdparty>/<subdir>/../..`

In `layout/application.html.erb`, I used absolute path to retrieve them; eg `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/dojoroot/dojo/resources/dojo.css" %>` and `<%= javascript_include_tag "/dojoroot/dojo/dojo.js" %>`

For Rails 3.2.6, the assets are expected to be in `app/assets` or `lib/assets`. However, moving the 3rd party from public to app/assets doesn't work because the tag are looking for the assets under their respective type. For example, `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "dojoroot/dojo/resources/dojo.css" %>` will look at `app/assets/stylesheet/dojoroot/dojo/resources/dojo.csc` and likewise the javascripts will look under `apps/assets/javascripts/dojoroot/dojo/dojo.js`. Breaking the 3rd party into 3 subdirs of stylesheets/javascripts/images seem rather wasteful and timeconsuming.

If I pass the absolute path to the tag; eg `<%= javascript_include_tag "/dojoroot/dojo/dojo.js" %>` Rails won't find it in app/assets/dojoroot.

Is there a configuration where I can have Rails look for the assets without injecting "stylesheets", "javascripts" into the path?

Answer (score 1):

Just name the file, no path

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "dojo" %>
```

If you want to reference more than one, you can do

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "dojo", "custom" %>
```

Also, make sure in app/assets/javascript/application.js that you have

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

And `<%= javascript_include_tag(:application) %>` in your `application.html.erb`

read '2.1.2 Using index files' in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html